# How does one hide a series programmatically on a dc.js series chart?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I have a dc-series chart that sometimes has a large disparity between the series, causing the smaller values to be almost unusable in certain cases. I've played around with filtering a dummy dimension, but I can't figure out how to only filter on just the seriesAccessor. `dimension.filterExact(['Total Sessions',oneDay]);` works to show a single day (which is the keyAccessor), but I can't figure out how to just simple hide (or show) one (or some) of the series.

#### Data like: (real data is JSON, but you get the idea)

```
'type','date','value'
'Total Sessions',1414800000000,200
'Total Sessions',1414886400000,300
'New Users',1414800000000,12
'New Users',1414886400000,5
```

#### Dimension/Group like:

```
var dimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) { return [d.type, +d.date]; });
var group = dimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.value });
```

#### Series chart like:

```
.seriesAccessor(function(d) { return "" + d.key[0]; })
.keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
.valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
```

Hope that makes sense!

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a built in way to do this, though there should be.

The series chart does support adding and removing series, however.

Probably your best bet for now is to simply filter out the data you don't want to see. You could add a dimension to do this, or you could create a [fake group](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#filter-the-data-before-its-charted) which hides bins based on their key.

Please [file an enhancement request](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/new) for this.

Comment: Issue added! Thanks for the quick response time, Gordon!

Comment: Thanks @scott_trinh. Is pre-filtering a reasonable workaround for now?

Comment: Yeah, I think I can work around it that way. Pre-render hook FTW!